# Steps to show that $\Phi(−z) = 1−\Phi(z)$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

The solution is to let $w = -v$. I determined that the steps are:

$$
\begin{split}
\Phi(-z) 
 &= \int_{-\infty}^{-z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-w^2}{2}}dw\\
 &= \int_{\infty}^{z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-v^2}{2}}(-dv)\\
 &= \int_{z}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-v^2}{2}}dv\\
 &= 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{z} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-v^2}{2}}dv
\end{split}
$$

the first 3 of these make sense to me. You first make the substitution, then you flip the limits of integration to cancel out the negative. But, the last step in the book I don't understand. I see that the limits are flipped back, and in this way they match the function $\Phi(z)$. However, I don't understand how to add a $1$ such that the integral is subtracted from it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $f$ is even then $F(x)=\int_0^x f(y)dy$ is odd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses the fact \begin{align*}
1 &= \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \Phi(z)  \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-v^2/2} \,\mathrm{d}v  \\
    &= \int_{-\infty}^z \; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-v^2/2} \,\mathrm{d}v  +  \int_z^\infty \; \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-v^2/2} \,\mathrm{d}v  \text{,}  
\end{align*}
where $z$ is any real number.  This is the relation used on the third and fourth lines of your display.

Equivalently, $\Phi$ is a cumulative density function and the total probability must be $1$.

Comment: This also makes use of evenness of the integrand, so the last statement about "equivalently" is not quite correct.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : There is no evenness of the integrand in use here.

Comment: In order to relate the integral from $z$ to $\infty$ to $\Phi(-z)$, evenness must be employed.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : I do not make that relation.  You seem to have conflated the Question with this Answer.

Comment: I was taking issue with your last statement being slightly misleading because to a novice, they might assume the result in the OP holds in general with how matter-of-factly you stated the "equivalently" bit. (Not all probability density functions have this property.)

Comment: @CameronWilliams : OP only asks about the step between lines 3 and 4 of the display in the Question.  This Answer is precisely responsive to the Question.  You seem to want an answer to a question that is not asked.

Comment: I've explained my position. It was simply a helpful comment to make sure someone new to the subject doesn't make a wrong assumption based on a misinterpretation of what you've written. I'm sorry I've somehow offended you with a little bit of feedback.

Comment: @CameronWilliams : And I have made my position clear: you are misrepresenting the Question or you are confused that the second claim in the writing form "Claim.  Equivalently, claim." can somehow refer to a claim other than the first.

Comment: That makes sense, I wasn’t sure whether or not I was supposed to say in general the statement is true or that it is true only for the normal CDF

Answer (score 4):

An alternative mode to prove the equation consist to use the proprety of the gaussian variables; in fact if $Z\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ then $aZ\sim N(a\mu,\sqrt{\lvert a\rvert}\sigma)$.

If $Z\sim N(0,1)$ then $-Z\sim N(0,1)$, $$\phi(-z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq-z)=1-\mathbb{P}(Z\geq-z)=1-\mathbb{P}(-Z\leq z)=1-\mathbb{P}(Z\leq z)=1-\phi(z)$$

Comment: I think the OP is still in the process of deriving these properties.

Comment: And here $\phi$ is usually reserved to denote the density function, not distribution function.

Comment: i use the fact that the law of gaussian variable is characterized from mean and variance

Comment: This explanation intuitively makes more sense. @WesleyStrik is right, however, even though I know this property we can't use it in the solution (yet).